# In a parallelogram $ ABCD, MN\parallel BD$. Prove that $\operatorname{Area}(\Delta MBC)=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta NCD).$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solution-verification, area

In the very beginning, I'm going to refer to a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2156218/721644) containing key information required in the following proof and especially the [answer by @EmilioNovati](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2156252/721644).

> On the edges $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AD}$ of the parallelogram $ABCD$ there are points $M$ and $N$ respectively s.t. $MN\parallel BD$. Prove that $\operatorname{Area}(\Delta MBC)=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta NCD).$

---

My approach:

Let $E$ be the intersection point of $BD$ and $CM$ and let $F$ be the intersection point of $BD$ and $CN$. Let's observe the triangles $\Delta BCE\;\&\;\Delta CDF$ and $\Delta BEM\;\&\;\Delta DFN$.

Let $C_1\in BD$ s.t. $CC_1\perp BD$. Then $\Delta BCE\;\&\;\Delta CDF$ have the common altitude $\overline{CC_1}$.

Let $M_1,N_1\in BD$ s. t. $MM_1\perp BD$ and $NN_1\perp BD.\;\implies MM_1\parallel NN_1.$

$MN\parallel BD\implies |MM_1|=|NN_1|$, so $\Delta BEM\;\&\;\Delta FDN$ have equal altitudes.

Now, the key part:

As @EmilioNovati stated in the answer in the thread, let $G$ be the intersection point of $MN$ and $CD$ and let $B_1$ be the intersection point of $BC$ and $MN$.

$AD\parallel BC\;\&\;MN\parallel BD\implies$ the quadrilateral $B_1BDN$ is a parallelogram and $|B_1B|=|DN|\implies\Delta B_1BM\cong\Delta NDG\implies |B_1M|=|GN|$

According to the *Thales intercept theorem*:
$$\frac{|BE|}{|B_1M|}=\frac{|DF|}{|GN|}\implies |BE|=|DF|$$

We obtain:

$$\color{red}{\operatorname{Area}(\Delta MBC)}=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta BEM)+\operatorname{Area}(\Delta BCE)=|BE|\frac{|MM_1|+|CC_1|}{2}\\=|DF|\frac{|NN_1|+|CC_1|}{2}=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta FDN)+\operatorname{Area}(\Delta CDF)=\color{red}{\operatorname{Area}(\Delta NCD)}\;\square$$

Picture:

[image]

May I ask if there is anything missing or how to improve my proof if necessary? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proof would be

$$\frac{\triangle MBC}{\triangle ABC} = \frac{MB}{AB} = \frac{ND}{AD} = \frac{\triangle NCD}{\triangle ACD}.$$

Since $\triangle ABC = \triangle ACD$, we are done.